How to change associated application of notification in UWP using IBackgroundTask
I have two UWP applications app1 and app2,
I have implemented notification of app1 which give notification on hardware change.
        private async void Hardware_Change(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
 
            var toastContentBuilder = new ToastContentBuilder()
                .AddArgument("action", "app2")
                .AddText("open hardware app")
                .AddText("Please Open Hardware App")
                .GetToastContent();
            var tost = new ToastNotification(toastContentBuilder.GetXml());
            ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(tost);
            Application.Current.Exit();

        }

I created Windows Runtime Component Project for IBackgroundTask and referenced in app1 project
    public sealed class LancherBackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
                var uri = new Uri("app2:");
                var options = new LauncherOptions();
                options.TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName = "app2_packge_family_name";
                var success = await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri, options);
        }
    }

then I registered the background task in package.appmanifest of app1.
and set entry point to IBackgroundTask class.
      <Extensions>
        <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="BackgroundHelper.LancherBackgroundTask">
          <BackgroundTasks>
            <Task Type="pushNotification"/>
          </BackgroundTasks>
        </Extension>
      </Extensions>

I am not able launch app2 from notification of app1.
every time app1 shows when clicked on notification, and I am not confirmed that IBackgroundTask is running or not.
How to work with IBackgroundTask in UWP? and how to open app2 from the notification of app1 without opening app1?


"how to open app2 from the notification of app1 without opening app1?"

Sorry, it is not possible to open another app using LaunchUriAsync in out-of process-backgroundtask, it is recommended that you handle it in process.
It is recommended to use Notification listener to open app2. You can refer to Background task for notification added/dismissed.
